# GORM Migrator Create Table without Indexes

Tags: database, go, orm, etl, go-gorm

I have the following situation:

I have a CLI app that runs several unatteneded processes, most of these are complex ETLs.
The normal workflow on these cases is:

1. Download several files from a S3 Bucket into a local PostgreSQL database, making some calculations
2. Process,calculate and aggregate all the info into a resulting dataset
3. Upload the results to a remote database

I am defining my model using tags as usual:

```golang
type SalesInfo struct {
    FieldA string `gorm:"index"`
    FieldB string `gorm:"index"`
    FieldC string `gorm:"index"`
    FieldD float64
    ...
    FieldZ float64
}

func (SalesInfo) TableName() string {
    return "salesinfo"
}
```

And then i create the structures (in fact i recreate the structures on each run) using a migrator:

```golang
// creates the Sales structures
func createStructures() error {

    log.Printf("Creating database structures\n")

    // LocalDB is a *gorm.DB defined elsewhere
    // Ctx is a context.Context defined elsewhere

    // table drops
    if err := LocalDB.WithContext(Ctx).Migrator().DropTable(&SalesInfo{}); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // table creations
    if err := LocalDB.WithContext(Ctx)AutoMigrate(&SalesInfo{}); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    log.Printf("All structures created\n")

    return nil

}
```

The result is a empty table with the corresponding indexes created.
The problem starts when i reach several hundreds of millions of records, the performance is really bad. The usual approach on a manual process here is to create the table without the indexes, dump the data, and create the indexes after.

The solution im using right now is: avoid the indexes on the model, and manually create the indexes after the insertions:

Model:

```golang
type SalesInfo struct {
    FieldA string /*`gorm:"index"`*/
    FieldB string /*`gorm:"index"`*/
    FieldC string /*`gorm:"index"`*/
    FieldD float64
    ...
    FieldZ float64
}

func (SalesInfo) TableName() string {
    return "salesinfo"
}
```

Manual Indexing:

```golang
// creates indexes for dumped data
func indexData() error {

    log.Printf("Indexing Dumped Data\n")

    log.Printf("Indexing FieldA...\n")
    if err := LocalDB.WithContext(Ctx).Exec(`Create index i_fielda on "salesinfo"("FieldA")`).Error; err != nil {
        return err
    }

    log.Printf("Indexing FieldB...\n")
    if err := LocalDB.WithContext(Ctx).Exec(`Create index i_fieldb on "salesinfo"("FieldB")`).Error; err != nil {
        return err
    }

    log.Printf("Indexing FieldC...\n")
    if err := LocalDB.WithContext(Ctx).Exec(`Create index i_fieldc on "salesinfo"("FieldC")`).Error; err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil

}
```

I don't like this because:

1. The model is not representative of the final structure
2. I need to code manually for each indexed field
3. Every time the model changes i need to check and modify code outside the model

---

So i'm trying to do a "delayed" index creation or a table without indexes creation approach but cant find a way using GORM

I've tryed this:

```golang
    if err := LocalDB.WithContext(Ctx).Migrator().CreateTable(&SalesInfo{}); err != nil {
        return err
    }
```

To use later something like this:

```golang
    if err := LocalDB.WithContext(Ctx).Migrator().CreateIndex(&SaesInfo{},"FieldA"); err != nil {
        return err
    }
```

But the table is created with the indexes on the first place

---

So my questions are:

1. Is there any way to create the table without the indexes using gorm?
2. Is there any way to create all the indexes defined on the struct in a single command?